# Ubuntu 18 no audio after new mobo

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, motherboard

I've changed my motherboard to a new one (ASUS TUF GAMING B550M PLUS) and I had two problems:
1 - No ethernet
2 - No audio
I've upgraded the kernel version and ethernet now works, but audio still does not. What can I do?
I need to stay with Ubuntu 18.04 unfortunately

Comment: Best practice after a significant hardware change is to reinstall the operating system. Your installed system includes software and configs for your old hardware. Sometimes you don't have to do this but presumably you got new hardware because it is an upgrade, so why would you not want to make sure that your system installation is optimized for that hardware

Comment: it's because reinstalling 18.04 comes with the old kernel and I don't have ethernet then, so I didn't want to do that

Comment: By that logic you still don't have Ethernet since you're running 18.04

Comment: I've upgraded the kernel alone, which fixes ethernet connection.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 media comes with a variety of kernels provided on the media; of which you've given no details (18.04 comes with 4.15, 18.04.2 with 4.18, 18.04.3 uses 5.0, 18.04.4 uses 5.3, 18.04.5 uses 5.4 for example, though they'll change post-upgrade), but we don't know anything about what you're using; there is no Ubuntu 18 (closest is a *snap* only Ubuntu Core 18 product, as the *year* format is used only for *snap* only products; all *deb* based systems use *year.month*).  Please clarify your details (*your title implies a different system to what you later mention*)

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't know that. I will look into it and update the question accordingly, thank you very much!